# Boost max flow algorithms do not compile. error: forming reference to void

Tags: boost, max-flow, edmonds-karp, push-relabel

Boost provides three different algorithms for finding max flow in directed graphs: **boykov_kolmogorov**, **edmonds_karp** and **push_relabel**. All of them have named and non-named parameter versions. Parameter sets they use are also very similar. Despite that, with same parameters some of these algorithms compile and some of them do not.

**push_relabel** compiles nicely with both named and non-named version:

```
  using Graph =
    boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
                        VertexProperty, EdgeProperty>;
  auto props = boost::capacity_map(capacity)
               .residual_capacity_map(residual_capacity)
               .reverse_edge_map(reverse_edge_map)
               .vertex_index_map(vertex_index_map)
               .color_map(color_map)
               .predecessor_map(predcessor_map)
               .distance_map(distance_map);
  boost::push_relabel_max_flow(g, s, t, props);
  boost::push_relabel_max_flow(g, s, t, capacity, residual_capacity,
                   reverse_edge_map, vertex_index_map);
```

**boykov_kolmogorov** compiles with non-named version:

```
  boost::boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow(g, capacity, residual_capacity,
                                    reverse_edge_map,
                                    vertex_index_map, s, t);
```

But fails with named version:

```
  boost::boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow(g, s, t, props);
```

> /celibs/boost_1_73_0/boost/graph/detail/adjacency_list.hpp:2768:17: error: forming reference to void

**edmonds_karp** fails with both named and non-named versions with same error:

```
boost::edmonds_karp_max_flow(g, s, t, props);
boost::edmonds_karp_max_flow(g, s, t, capacity, residual_capacity, reverse_edge_map,
                          color_map, predcessor_map);
```

> /celibs/boost_1_73_0/boost/concept_check.hpp:147:9: error: use of deleted function

Full example is here: https://godbolt.org/z/dvjfec

Do I pass parameters in incorrect way? How to pass them correctly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This indeed seems to be a bug.

It appears that the `choose_const_pmap` for `edge_capacity` fails when there is no interior `edge_capacity_t` property defined ([Interior Properties](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_74_0/libs/graph/doc/using_property_maps.html#sec:interior-properties)).

Defining one makes the problem go away. However, we can check that it always takes precedence over the one provided via named paramaters:

```
struct Oops {};
using EdgeProperty = boost::property<boost::edge_capacity_t, Oops>;
```

Leads to compilation problems, suggesting that the wrong property map is selected.

I could not find an obvious cause for this behaviour - all the other named arguments behave as expected, and are declared in very similar fashion (the process is automated by macro). I assume there will be something very subtle involved (like a name collision or ADL mishap?).

Here's the code that works for me:

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jts5o0nG6tK0zx0m)** (note obviously can't run successfully, because it doesn't satisfy any invariants)

```
#define BOOST_ALLOW_DEPRECATED_HEADERS
#include <boost/config.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/edmonds_karp_max_flow.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/graph_utility.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/push_relabel_max_flow.hpp>
#include <boost/property_map/function_property_map.hpp>

int main() {
    struct VertexProperty final {};
    // struct EdgeProperty final {};
    using EdgeProperty = boost::property<boost::edge_capacity_t, int>;
    using Graph =
        boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
                              VertexProperty, EdgeProperty>;
    using Edge = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor;
    using Vertex = boost::graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_descriptor;
    auto g = Graph{};
    auto s = Vertex{};
    auto t = Vertex{};

    auto residualCapacityMap = std::vector<int>{};
    auto reverseEdgeMap = std::vector<Edge>{};
    auto colorMap = std::vector<boost::default_color_type>{};
    auto predcessorMap = std::vector<Edge>{};
    auto distanceMap = std::vector<int>{};

    auto vertex_index_map =
        boost::make_function_property_map<Vertex>([](Vertex) { return 0; });
    auto edge_index_map =
        boost::make_function_property_map<Edge>([](Edge) { return 0; });
    // auto capacity = boost::make_function_property_map<Edge>( [](Edge) { return 0; });
    auto capacity = boost::get(boost::edge_capacity, g);
    auto residual_capacity = boost::make_iterator_property_map(
        residualCapacityMap.begin(), edge_index_map);
    auto reverse_edge_map = boost::make_iterator_property_map(
        reverseEdgeMap.begin(), edge_index_map);
    auto color_map =
        boost::make_iterator_property_map(colorMap.begin(), vertex_index_map);
    auto predcessor_map = boost::make_iterator_property_map(
        predcessorMap.begin(), vertex_index_map);
    auto distance_map = boost::make_iterator_property_map(distanceMap.begin(),
                                                          vertex_index_map);

    auto props = boost::capacity_map(capacity)
                     .residual_capacity_map(residual_capacity)
                     .reverse_edge_map(reverse_edge_map)
                     .vertex_index_map(vertex_index_map)
                     .color_map(color_map)
                     .predecessor_map(predcessor_map)
                     .distance_map(distance_map);

    boost::push_relabel_max_flow(g, s, t, props);
    boost::push_relabel_max_flow(g, s, t, capacity, residual_capacity,
                                 reverse_edge_map, vertex_index_map);

    boost::boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow(g, capacity, residual_capacity,
                                      reverse_edge_map, vertex_index_map, s, t);
    boost::boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow(g, s, t, props);

    boost::edmonds_karp_max_flow(g, s, t, props);
    boost::edmonds_karp_max_flow(g, s, t, capacity, residual_capacity,
                                 reverse_edge_map, color_map, predcessor_map);
}
```

As you can see all of the algorithm invocations now compile.

Comment: Please consider reporting the issue with the library devs, https://github.com/boostorg/graph/issues

Comment: Thanks a lot! Created an issue on github: https://github.com/boostorg/graph/issues/232

Comment: The bug was resolved today - see https://github.com/boostorg/graph/issues/232#issuecomment-1193434708