# Boost graph clear_out_edges argument mismatch

Tags: boost, boost-graph

According to https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/libs/graph/doc/adjacency_list.html

the declaration of `clear_out_edges` is:

`void clear_out_edges(vertex_descriptor u, adjacency_list& g)`

I have the following in my file:

```
typedef adjacency_list<
    vecS, vecS, directedS,

    property<
    vertex_name_t, std::string,
    property<vertex_index_t, int,
    property<vertex_color_t, boost::default_color_type,
    property<vertex_distance_t, double,
    property<vertex_predecessor_t, Traits::edge_descriptor>
    > > > >,

    property<
    edge_index_t, int,
    property<edge_capacity_t, double,
    property<edge_weight_t, double,
    property<edge_residual_capacity_t, double,
    property<edge_reverse_t, Traits::edge_descriptor>
> > > > >
Graph;

Graph g;
```

In trying to clear the edges by visiting all of the vertices via:

```
Graph::vertex_iterator v, vend;
for(boost::tie(v, vend) = vertices(g); v != vend; ++v){
    boost::clear_out_edges(v, g);//line in question
}
```

the compiler complains that:

`no instance of overloaded function "boost::clear_out_edges" matches the argument list -- argument types are: (boost::range_detail::integer_iterator<std::size_t>, Graph)C/C++(304)`

I am surprised by this, since `g` is an object of class `adjacency_list` via the typedef.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using `v` as if it is a descriptor, but it's an iterator. Dereference it:

```
clear_out_edges(*v, g);
```

May I suggest modernizing a bit, and perhaps using bundled properties and less `using namespace`? Too much code is being copy-pasted from ancient documentation samples which are written to still compile on c++03.

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/VyD6v9hCUTcuqAHQ)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
using namespace boost;

using Traits = adjacency_list_traits<vecS, vecS, directedS>;
using Graph  = adjacency_list<
    vecS, vecS, directedS,

    property<vertex_name_t, std::string,
    property<vertex_index_t, int,
    property<vertex_color_t, boost::default_color_type,
    property<vertex_distance_t, double,
    property<vertex_predecessor_t,
     Traits::edge_descriptor>>>>>,

    property<edge_index_t, int,
    property<edge_capacity_t, double,
    property<edge_weight_t, double,
    property<edge_residual_capacity_t, double,
    property<edge_reverse_t,
     Traits::edge_descriptor>>>>>>;

int main()
{
    Graph g(10);
    for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
        clear_out_edges(v, g);
    }
}
```

Or even better, depending on tastes. Note that at least `vertex_index` is very redundant with `vecS` and may actively harm your code correctness.

### UPDATE

Some hints about modernizing the code, and perhaps separating the graph model from algorithm specific metadata.

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/FEcYLy3DnZg4hlhr)**

```
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/edmonds_karp_max_flow.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow.hpp>

struct VertexProps { std::string name; };
struct EdgeProps { double capacity = 0, weight = 0, residual = 0; };

using Graph = boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
                                    VertexProps, EdgeProps>;

using V = Graph::vertex_descriptor;
using E = Graph::edge_descriptor;

int main()
{
    Graph g(10);
    for (auto v : boost::make_iterator_range(vertices(g))) {
        clear_out_edges(v, g);
    }

    auto idmap = get(boost::vertex_index, g);
    std::vector<boost::default_color_type> colors(num_vertices(g));
    std::vector<E> predecessors(num_vertices(g));
    std::vector<double> distances(num_vertices(g));

    auto weightmap = get(&EdgeProps::weight, g);
    auto capacity_map = get(&EdgeProps::capacity, g);
    auto residual_map = get(&EdgeProps::residual, g);

    std::map<E, E> reverse_edges;

    V src  = 0;
    V sink = 1;

    boost::edmonds_karp_max_flow(
        g, src, sink,
        boost::color_map(colors.data())
            .vertex_index_map(idmap)
            .distance_map(distances.data())
            .predecessor_map(predecessors.data())
            .weight_map(weightmap)
            .capacity_map(capacity_map)
            .residual_capacity_map(residual_map)
            .reverse_edge_map(boost::make_assoc_property_map(reverse_edges)));
}
```

> Keep in mind that there's a known issue with `boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow` (see [Boost max flow algorithms do not compile. error: forming reference to void](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64734193/boost-max-flow-algorithms-do-not-compile-error-forming-reference-to-void/64744086#64744086) and https://github.com/boostorg/graph/issues/232).

Comment: Thank you, as always for your detailed answers. I was indeed working on a max flow problem and the example you have provided is very pertinent.