# What does negative flow on a reverse arc of a graph in Boykov-Kolmogorov max flow algorithm mean?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph, boost, max-flow

In trying to solve the example problem provided on Boost's website: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/graph/example/boykov_kolmogorov-eg.cpp
(the code has to be run as `<executable> < max_flow.dat` where `max_flow.dat` comes along with boost installation at `\boost\lib\graph\example\`)

with the small change of displaying all flows by commenting out the line

`if (capacity[*ei] > 0)` provides the following output:

```
c  The total flow:
s 13

c flow values:
f 0 6 3
f 0 1 6
f 0 2 4
f 0 1 0
f 0 2 0
f 1 0 -6
f 1 5 1
f 1 0 0
f 1 3 5
f 1 3 0
f 2 0 -4
f 2 4 4
f 2 3 0
f 2 0 0
f 2 3 0
f 3 1 -5
f 3 2 0
f 3 7 5
f 3 2 0
f 3 1 0
f 4 2 -4
f 4 5 0
f 4 6 4
f 4 5 0
f 4 6 0
f 5 1 -1
f 5 4 0
f 5 4 0
f 5 7 1
f 5 7 0
f 6 0 0
f 6 4 -4
f 6 7 7
f 6 4 0
f 6 7 0
f 7 3 -5
f 7 5 -1
f 7 6 -4
f 7 6 0
f 7 5 0
```

My questions are:

(1) Given the display loop:

```
graph_traits < Graph >::vertex_iterator u_iter, u_end;
graph_traits < Graph >::out_edge_iterator ei, e_end;
for (boost::tie(u_iter, u_end) = vertices(g); u_iter != u_end; ++u_iter)
    for (boost::tie(ei, e_end) = out_edges(*u_iter, g); ei != e_end; ++ei)
         cout << ...
```

Why are some arcs displayed multiple times in the output for e.g.,

```
f 6 4 -4
f 6 4 0
```

Are we not just iterating sequentially through each out edge of each vertex? So, where does the repetition come from?

(2) Focussing on, say, node 6, and nonzero flows to/from it, there are 3 inflows 0 -> 6 of 3, 4 -> 6 of 4 and 7 -> 6 of -4, and 2 outflows of 6 -> 4 of -4 and 6 -> 7 of 7. This leads me to believe that the net inflow (total incoming flow - total outgoing flow) is 0 for each node in the final optimal solution. Does the algorithm guarantee that the eventual flows produced by the algorithm [the paper is available [here](https://www.csd.uwo.ca/%7Eyboykov/Papers/pami04.pdf)] will satisfy the requirement that the net inflow into a node, any node, in the graph will be 0? Related to this, what is the right "interpretation" of the flow from 7 -> 6 being -4 in the example above?

Cross posted on github also: https://github.com/boostorg/graph/issues/366

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> **Q.** (1) Given the display loop: Why are some arcs displayed multiple times in the output for e.g.,

The reverse edges are added (with capacity 0) in read_dimacs_max_flow, as required for the algorithm to work. The sample `max_flow.dat` contains both (4,6) and (6,4) with capacity 20.

This causes the respective reverse edges to appear with 0 capacity.

***Note** the file will refer to them as 5,7 respectively 7,5*.

> **Q.** Does the algorithm guarantee that the eventual flows produced by the algorithm [the paper is available here] will satisfy the requirement that the net inflow into a node, any node, in the graph will be 0?

Yes. See the documentation here: [Network Flow Algorithms](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_84_0/libs/graph/doc/graph_theory_review.html#sec:network-flow-algorithms) where it lists the three constraints on the flow function:

- f(u,v) <= c(u,v) for all (u,v) in V x V (Capacity constraint)
- f(u,v) = - f(v,u) for all (u,v) in V x V (Skew symmetry)
- sumv in V f(u,v) = 0 for all v in V - {s,t} (Flow conservation)

The third bullet codifies the constraint you were asking about.

> **Q.** Related to this, what is the right "interpretation" of the flow from 7 -> 6 being -4 in the example above?

There is no interpretation. Edges with zero capacity will typically be reverse edges, which is why the output omits them altogether.

In my understanding, the residual capacity on such reverse edges is required as bookkeeping for the algorithm. I agree the reverse edge modeling and mapping feel like a leaky abstraction (implementation details), but I'm sure there's a historical reason/convention for implementations to do this (e.g. to stay close to the original algorithm papers).

### DEMO TIME

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1b4eb0dc9ce343c5)**

Here's a toy program that shows you some more detail and checks invariants along the way, using more modern C++ so it's less hurtful to the eyes too:

```cpp
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow.hpp>
#include <boost/graph/read_dimacs.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <ranges>
#include <string>
namespace r = std::ranges;
namespace v = std::ranges::views;

using Traits = boost::adjacency_list_traits<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS>;
using Graph  = boost::adjacency_list<
    boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::directedS,
    boost::property<
        boost::vertex_name_t, std::string,
        boost::property<boost::vertex_index_t, long,
                        boost::property<boost::vertex_color_t, boost::default_color_type,
                                        boost::property<boost::vertex_distance_t, long,
                                                        boost::property<boost::vertex_predecessor_t,
                                                                        Traits::edge_descriptor>>>>>,
    boost::property<boost::edge_capacity_t, long,
                    boost::property<boost::edge_residual_capacity_t, long,
                                    boost::property<boost::edge_reverse_t, Traits::edge_descriptor>>>>;

int main() {
    using boost::make_iterator_range;
    Graph g;

    auto cap     = get(boost::edge_capacity, g);
    auto res_cap = get(boost::edge_residual_capacity, g);
    auto rev     = get(boost::edge_reverse, g);

    Graph::vertex_descriptor s{}, t{};
    read_dimacs_max_flow(g, cap, rev, s, t);

    std::vector<boost::default_color_type> color(num_vertices(g));
    std::vector<long>                      distance(num_vertices(g));

    auto dump = [&g, cap, res_cap] {
        std::cout << "c flow values:\n";
        std::cout << "# s t" /*"\tcap\tres."*/ "\tflow\n";
        for (auto u : make_iterator_range(vertices(g)))
            for (auto e : make_iterator_range(out_edges(u, g)))
                if (cap[e] > 0)
                    std::cout << "f " << u << " " << target(e, g) //
                           // << "\t" << cap[e]                   //
                           // << "\t" << res_cap[e]               //
                              << "\t" << (cap[e] - res_cap[e])    //
                              << std::endl;
    };

    // std::cout << "# before\n";
    // dump();

    // pre-conditions, checks
    auto const cap_vw = make_iterator_range(edges(g)) | v::transform([=](auto e) { return cap[e]; });
    std::vector const saved_caps(cap_vw.begin(), cap_vw.end());

    assert(r::none_of(make_iterator_range(edges(g)), [res_cap](auto e) { return res_cap[e]; }));

    long flow = boykov_kolmogorov_max_flow(g, s, t);

    std::cout << "# after\n";
    std::cout << "c  The total flow:" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "s " << flow << std::endl << std::endl;

    std::vector const result_caps(cap_vw.begin(), cap_vw.end());
    // capacities never change, so filtering for cap[e]>0 filters on the input property
    assert(saved_caps == result_caps);
    dump();
}
```

Printing

```
# after
c  The total flow:
s 13

c flow values:
# s t   flow
f 0 6   3
f 0 1   6
f 0 2   4
f 1 5   1
f 1 0   0
f 1 3   5
f 2 4   4
f 2 3   0
f 2 0   0
f 3 7   5
f 3 2   0
f 3 1   0
f 4 5   0
f 4 6   4
f 5 4   0
f 5 7   1
f 6 7   7
f 6 4   0
f 7 6   0
f 7 5   0
```

Comment: Note that I'd consider it more elegant to have some of the bookkeeping properties either outside the graph model or as bundled properties. In that case you supply the relevant property-maps via (named) params. Keep in mind that there have been some rough edges around the named-parameter support, see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/64744086/85371

Comment: could you let me know how your code on coliru reads the dimacs file? On my home machine, I had to invoke it as a.out < max_flow.dat, while in your case, you are able to just call read_dimacs_max_flow() directly? Also, I do not see "skew-symmetry" being satisfied in the solution I had posted. flow from 0 to 6 is 3, while flow from 6 to 0 is 0.

Comment: I used `printf` to print the content to stdin

Comment: Re: 'skew symmetry not satisfied' I feel this is tautologous with the question I just answered with "There is no interpretation." - the constraint is a given, I think the 0-cap edges are just not to be interpreted. If my interpretation is correct, the documentation could be significantly improved, because right now time doesn't permit me to dive into the code and algorithm papers to verify